# Android volley library doesn't keeping good quality image

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library to download image from network and to retain image in cache for later usage. volley is serving all my need.but the strange behavior is, it keeps good quality image based on the network speed , what surprised me is that, in 2G network it keeps poor quality image but in WI-Fi, it keeps very good quality. i am stuck here to find out root cause of this behavior. if you have faced this problem before , please share your knowledge what is happening in library, why it behaving differently on different speed, how i can keep same quality irrespective of any speed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Volley library is manage network speed automatically we can't adjust with it.
but if you want to good image quality every time than you can use following image loader

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[Facebook fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. how you say volley manages network speed automatically, have you gone through code base of volley, what specific classes are responsible for this behavior. what makes volley to work as similar as Universal Image Loader

Answer (score 0):

Try to load images with Picasso it will work separately. Just one line to add

Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView);